# OS X/ iOS Password Managers

Tags: macos, ios, applications

So I have been reading some articles today and I see the 1Password app coming up a lot. Is there anything special with it? I am currently using Wallet for both OS X and iOS and it does its job quite well. I was just curious because Wallet got 23 reviews while 1Password seems to be a lot more popular.

Is there anything making that app better than its competitors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat: I'm not familiar with Wallet.

After reading [this article](http://mac.appstorm.net/reviews/security/head-to-head-putting-wallet-1password-to-the-test/), my guess is the reason why users prefer 1Password is because of its browser integration and ability to auto-fill web login forms and the like depending on browser URL. This is one of 1Password's key selling feature.

Evidently Wallet does have some form of auto-fill, but it only supports Safari. 1Password supports nearly every major Mac browser. Also, according to that article, you have to type in your password every time you visit a new site and need to login. It may be more secure this way, but I'm sure most people prefer to automatically login if they have unlocked their keychain (which of course can be locked after a set period of inactivity.)

If I'm reading Wallet's [homepage](http://www.moxier.com/wallet/) correctly, for device-to-device synchronization, a premium subscription is required. The data is then synched to Moxier's servers. 1Password uses the popular [Dropbox](http://db.tt/HELDIz4V) (referral link) service for its synchronization, and is therefore free. (A basic Dropbox account includes 2 GB of free space.)

So, for those two reasons alone (easy web logins on every browser, free device-to-device synchronization) I would not replace 1Password with Wallet. If you don't require these features, keep on truckin'.

Comment: Wallet does support dropbox sync and Safari + chrome. In any case thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

1Password started as OS X-only, so it's more popular among long-time Mac/iOS users. Their Mac/iOS support should (theoretically) be better because it's their original platform.

That said, I use LastPass on OS X and iOS (and, occasionally, Windows and WebOS) and I'm quite happy with it. I haven't heard of any one cloud password management being significantly particularly better than its competitors nowadays.